# Flagging duplicates, with suggestions

Tags: feature-request

When you go to flag a post as a duplicate it should show the "Related Questions" list that a poster gets after he has entered a title.    What I'm thinking is there is something on top of that list that is an exact duplicate,  but the OP didn't see it.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment, but I'm not convinced that the actual duplicate shows up in the "related questions" list often enough to make this worthwhile.  I generally find duplicate questions by using Google, not the Related Questions dialog.

Comment: @Robert Harvey♦  There should be something better than just a blank textbox.

Comment: Flag for dupe?

Flag?

You shouldn't be mod-flagging dupes.  [You should stop worrying and love dupes.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)  *Unless it is a 100% exact dupe,* of course; they usually need special attention.

I'm sure you meant "Closing as duplicates, with suggestions."  Right?

Comment: @Will♦  yeah but posts are still going to be flagged as dupes,  you should make the system more clean and easier to use.